# custom parsley validation not working

Tags: parsley.js

validation is not working with the following custom validation (all other standard validation html attributes are working). I have removed inputs in the form that are not applicable.

```
 <form id="regForm" role="form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="wards">Your Ward</label>



<select name="fields[ward]" class="form-control">
<option value="" selected="selected">SELECT WARD</option>
<option value="item">item 1</option>
</select>
        <p class="help-block">It is important that you select the ward your current membership records reside in!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="wardOther">Other Ward or Not in Australia?</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="wardOther" name="fields[wardOther]" rows="4"  data-parsley-conditionalrequired='[name=\"fields[ward]\"] option:selected' data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class="" data-parsley-conditionalrequired-message="This value is required since you did not select an australian ward!"></textarea>
            <p class="help-block">Please tell us the Country, Stake, Ward, and Bishops Name you are attending from</p>
      </div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#regForm').parsley({
    validators: {
      conditionalrequired: {
        fn: function (value, requirements) {
          console.log('fdsafds');
      if ($(requirements).val() == '' && '' == value)
      return false; 


          return true;
        },
        priority: 32
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

The console.log is not triggering.

Answer (score 1):

The customer validator is not working at your case because you didn't specify the form name value and "data-parsley-validate" to the form definition.

```
<form id="regForm" role="form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Just add name="regForm" and it should work properly.

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" role="form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-parsley-validate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a bit [different approach](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/extra/validator/comparison.js) for creating custom validator. You can see the working example here http://jsfiddle.net/Hmhjy/

```
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('conditionalrequired', 
function (value, requirement) {
    console.log('fdsafds');
    if ($(requirements).val() == '' && '' == value) {
        return false; 
    }

    return false;
}, 32)
.addMessage('en', 'conditionalrequired', 'This value is required since you did not select an australian ward!');

$('#regForm').parsley();
```